# Application failed to start because platform plugin “windows” is missing

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I am developing an application in QT.

It runs on Windows 7 and Windows 8, but on Windows XP it produces [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sQSu.jpg) error.

These are the `dll` files that I have added in my `exe` file directory

```
libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
libstdc++-6.dll
libwinpthread-1.dll
Qt5Core.dll
Qt5Gui.dll
Qt5Widgets.dll
QT5Svg.dll
QT5Sql.dll
```

These are folders included in the directory:

```
imageformats
platforms
sqldrivers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to explicitly add plugin paths at the beginning of the main, like this:

```
QStringList paths = QCoreApplication::libraryPaths();
paths.append(".");
paths.append("imageformats");
paths.append("platforms");
QCoreApplication::setLibraryPaths(paths);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you put `qwindows.dll` on platforms? Your app layout should look like this:

```
app.exe  
Qt5Core.dll  
Qt5Gui.dll  
Qt5Widgets.dll  
platforms  
--qwindows.dll  
--qminimal.dll  
imageformats  
--qjp2.dll  
--...
```

Comment: Yes i have added qwindows.dll
My app works fine for windows 7 and windows 8 but it does not work on windows xp